# SQL Server Insert statement taking 9 minutes for a particular group, but only sometimes

Tags: sql-server

I have a large insert statement in my code (Roughly 50,000 entries per insert on average), that usually completes within 2 seconds or so for each 'group'. One of these groups is a smaller one called PRL (roughly 20,000 per insert), and for that group, maybe 1 in 10 times, the insert will take 9 minutes in total.

I have narrowed this down to being the SELECT statement itself, as I've modified the proc to first insert into a temp table, and then the actual table itself, and we now see the delay on the temp table first, and then the actual table takes 2 seconds or so as expected.

We thought this may be due to parameter sniffing, where SQL is creating a query plan for the other larger groups, and then getting the plan wrong for PRL. However, my manager has told me to scrap this idea as we would also see this for other groups, and not just PRL exclusively (There's roughly 15 groups or so).

Does anyone have any references or ideas on how I can investigate this problem further? I've also investigated the table we're inserting into and its clustered indexes, but there's only one clustered index and from what I gather, inserts being a problem usually only occur on tables with multiple clustered columnstores.

Thanks for any help in advance, and sorry for being a bit vague. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Seems like a disk I/O bottle neck. If you monitor the "Disk Queue Length" and "Disk sec/Transfer" performance counters on the volume/s hosting tempdb do they spike for the duration of the tempdb insert time? Are they backed by a RAID array, by chance, that has a failing disk?

Comment: Query plan would help, please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. What result do you get from `select status, blocking_session_id, wait_type, wait_time, wait_resource, cpu_time, reads, writes from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id = @YourBlockedSession`. If `blocking_session_id` is not null, what is the result from *that* session?